# Searching one column in a data frame for specific words

Tags: python, string, pandas

Here is the data frame I have:
[Current data frame structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZHJg.png)

As you can see in the address column I have the full address, however I want to do a search to find out how many entries have, 'County Armagh', 'County Down', 'County Tyrone' etc within their address.

Any idea how I could **search through the address column of this dataframe for certain counties** and print out the rows or do a count on them?

Here are some things I've already tried:

```
print(addressCrimes.Address.find("County Armagh"))

locat= addressCrimes[addressCrimes["Address"].isin(["County Armagh"])]
```

Comment: `print(addressCrimes[addressCrimes.Adrress=="County Armagh"])` the dumbest solution but possible. can also use `strip()` and `contains()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
addressCrimes[addressCrimes.Address.str.contains("Country Armagh")]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use regex, or matching, with the `pandas.String` method `str`. If you have a list `['County Armagh', 'County Down', 'County Tyrone']` then you can use `str.contains`, or `str.match`.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

counties = ['County Armagh', 'County Down', 'County Tyrone', 'County Clay']

s = pd.Series([random.choice(counties) for x in range(100)])

s.str.contains(counties[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. If it doesn't work please make your table able to be copied and pasted!

```
FindCounty = lambda x: x.find('County Armagh') if x.find('County Armagh') > -1 else "None"
addressCrimes['FindResult'] = AddressCrimes.apply(FindCount)
```